# Highcharts: Solidgauge Shadows

Tags: highcharts

In the Highcharts API, they have have 'shadow' listed as a property for solidgauge [plotOptions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.solidgauge.shadow) as well as for solidgauge [series](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.shadow), but in neither case does it appear to make any difference. Working in my own project and on the Highcharts jsfiddle demo it just doesn't seem to do anything if I set it to true or assign an object with specific properties. Am I doing something wrong or is this just the way it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug - I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7512

As a **workaround** you can apply SVG `defs` pattern like in this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/ckLmz931/

**JS:**

```
  defs: {
    glow: {
      tagName: 'filter',
      id: 'shadow',
      opacity: 1,
      children: [{
        tagName: 'feGaussianBlur',
        result: 'coloredBlur',
        stdDeviation: 5
      }, {
        tagName: 'feMerge',
        children: [{
          tagName: 'feMergeNode',
          in : 'coloredBlur'
        }, {
          tagName: 'feMergeNode',
          in : 'SourceGraphic'
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
```

**CSS**

```
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

.highcharts-point {
    filter: url(#shadow);
}
```

---

**Docs demo about `defs`:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

Comment: Thanks for this. I had considered reporting the bug, but I wanted to be sure it was a bug first. :)